# NetBeans stops underlining errors in NetBeans refactored code

Tags: java, netbeans, refactoring, package, highlighting

I'm having somewhat of a strange problem with NetBeans.  I'm creating a program in Java that has multiple packages in it.  I created 2 new classes for the project, but immediately afterwards I realized that I put them in the wrong package.  So, I clicked the name of the class in the projects panel, dragged it to the appropriate package, and released.  NetBeans then asked if I wanted it to refactor my code. This was the first time I've done this so I decided to preview it.  It looked fine (just changed the package name) so I went ahead and moved the 2 classes over, allowing NetBeans to refactor them.  This is where my problem comes in.

I realized while coding that NetBeans is no longer underlining the errors in my code, yet-to-be-finished lines, etc.  It is instead just italicising the font.  I thought this was strange so I decided to test it out in another class and for some reason everything worked fine in the other class.  **It turns out that NetBeans is only giving me this strange behavior in the 2 classes that it moved and refactored.**

So I looked online and saw that you could change what NetBeans does with errors in Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Syntax -> Category Error.  I figured this would't work because this was obviously a preferences page for "everything."  My settings were fine, so I changed the error setting, applied the change, and then changed it back to try and "re-force" the error highlighting preferences.  Now NetBeans doesn't underline errors *anywhere*, and only italicises them.

In addition, the syntax highlighting preferences for *everything* (default, character, comment, etc.) that did not already have any effects color or effects setting now show "Effects: Wave Underline Effects Color: Red".  And if that wasn't weird enough, they don't even "red underline."  I've tried closing and reopening the classes and restarting NetBeans but nothing's working.

I took screenshots but unfortunately I can't post them because I don't have 10 Rep.  Did I break my NetBeans?  Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Even though my error setting were correct:
Effects: Wave Underline
Effects Color: Red,
restoring the default NetBeans settings for Fonts & Colors fixed my problem.  Must have been some sort of strange bug?

Comment: Close Netbeans, delete the cache directory and delete or move your configuration user directory. (See http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir), restart Netbeans and reopen the project. If that doesn't fix the problem, can you upload the whole project somewhere such as GitHub so I can check your project settings where you put the files etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is too late, but a have de same issue.

Try with `Windows>Reset Windows`.

In my case only happens in one class.

Answer (score -2):

I had exactly the same problem with NetBeans 8.1 pressing 'Restore' and restarting worked for me.

Comment: Downvote could have come because the answer was vague (where is Restore?) or because it didn't work for them, as it didn't work for me.

Comment: Where is "restore" ??